# Flip Sprite using the SpriteRenderer component

Tags: c#, unity3d

I want to create a 2D topdown game with Unity. When moving the player I also want him to rotate.

Most tutorials provide a solution changing the localscale of the transform component on the x axis setting -1 for left movement and 1 for right movement.

The attached SpriteRenderer component also got `flipX` and `flipY` checkboxes. I think setting these checkboxes by code might be more efficient.

Using this example code achieves the desired rotation

```
bool flipX;
bool flipY;

void Update()
{   
    float horizontalInput = movementDirection.x;

    if (horizontalInput > 0)
    {
        flipX = false;
    }
    else if (horizontalInput < 0)
    {
        flipX = true;
    }

    float verticalInput = movementDirection.y;

    if (verticalInput > 0)
    {
        flipY = false;
    }
    else if (verticalInput < 0)
    {
        flipY = true;
    }

    spriteRenderer.flipX = flipX;
    spriteRenderer.flipY = flipY;
}
```

My question is: Is there a way avoiding these four if-statements? Maybe there is a more optimized way using some math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need people to review your code you have to give a complete bunch of working code. 
Here, we can only make assumptions about how what you show interoperate with what you don't show.

Your `movementDirection..x` and `movementDirection..y` can only be `-1`, `0`, `1`. Correct?
So, why using `float`s instead of `int`s ? Or even better, an `enum`, per example:

```
enum Movement
{
    Backward = -1,
    None = 0,
    Forward = 1      
};
```

You only need flipping sprite if movements are negatives (for each axis). That's right?

Why just don't test for backwarding movement and set `flipX` to false otherwise (same for Y).

```
void Update()
{   
    flipX = (movementDirection.x == Movement.Backward);
    flipY = (movementDirection.y == Movement.Backward);

    spriteRenderer.flipX = flipX;
    spriteRenderer.flipY = flipY;
}
```

**Edit:**
That's in case of neutral fixed states (Movement.None never flipped).
If when no movement you want to keep the last flipped states you still want two statement by axis.

```
void Update()
{   
    if  (movementDirection.x != Movement.None)
        flipX = (movementDirection.x == Movement.Backward);
    if  (movementDirection.y != Movement.None)
        flipY = (movementDirection.y == Movement.Backward);

    spriteRenderer.flipX = flipX;
    spriteRenderer.flipY = flipY;
}
```

**Edit 2:**

For completeness, if you really want to minimize statements, you can use Convert, but i dont think it will improve performances :

```
void Update()
{   
    if  (movementDirection.x != Movement.None)
        flipX = Convert.ToBoolean(movementDirection.x - 1);
    if  (movementDirection.y != Movement.None)
        flipY = Convert.ToBoolean(movementDirection.y - 1);

    spriteRenderer.flipX = flipX;
    spriteRenderer.flipY = flipY;
}
```

Comment: The class fields also seem redundant... I'd make everything local to the method.

Comment: Look at my edit. In his original code, he doesnt change FlipX value from the precious in case of no movement.